# Jenkins Pipeline : java.io.NotSerializableException: java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate Error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am executing the following attached code in Jenkins Pipeline. I get the following error - java.io.NotSerializableException: java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate. However, when I create individual piepline projects for each  of the stages in the pipeline, they run without any error. For example, the jenkins pipeline attached fails to call the stage 'Execute Shell' which is after stage "Build".But when I stitch all of the pipelines together into stages in a single pipeline. I am not able to do that.

Request you to help me in resolving the issue.

```
Below is the Jenkins file:


import java.security.*;
import java.io.*

node {

  def mvnHome = tool 'M3'
    git url: 'https://github.com/s88888/CDCD1.git'
    def server = Artifactory.server 'Artifactory_Local'

    stage "Build"
    def uploadSpec_heatTemplate = readFile 'Test.yaml'    

    stage 'Execute Shell'
    sh 'whoami'

    // Get Artifactory server instance, defined in the Artifactory Plugin administration page.


   stage 'Package Verify'

        // Get Artifactory server instance, defined in the Artifactory Plugin administration page.

        // Create the upload spec.

        def uploadSpec1 = """{
            "files": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "jenkins-pipeline-example/resources/ABC.zip",
                        "target": "libs-snapshot-local",
                        "props": "p1=v1;p2=v2"
                    }
                ]
            }"""

        // Upload to Artifactory.
        def buildInfo1 = server.upload spec: uploadSpec1
        // Create the download spec.
        def downloadSpec = """{
            "files": [
                    {
                        "pattern": "libs-snapshot-local/*(ABC).zip",
                        "target": "test/",
                        "props": "p1=v1;p2=v2"
                    }
                ]
            }"""

        // Download from Artifactory.

        def buildInfo2 = server.download spec: downloadSpec
        // Publish the build to Artifactory
        server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo2


     stage 'Final'
    sh "echo 'Done with pipeline'"


}


Below is the error:

Running on master in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/E2EWorkflow
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] stage (Build)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage Build
Proceeding
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
f87ca3d668934f2f06c73ea70b5432d8
[Pipeline] stage (Execute Shell)
Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated
Entering stage Execute Shell
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[E2EWorkflow] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1785)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1362)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:967)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeMap.writeObject(TreeMap.java:2438)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:271)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:132)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:452)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:427)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:415)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:360)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
    in field locals
    in field caller
    in field e
    in field program
    in field threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@13e9cfc7
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the unnecessary `import` statements from the top of your Pipeline and it will work.

All the code used within a Pipeline has to be serialisable, and you're importing Java classes which have static initialisers, which even although unused, will cause problems.

You should also note the "Using the ‘stage’ step without a block argument is deprecated" error message that you're getting, and use the correct syntax, e.g.:

```
// Correct
stage('Build') {
    …
}

// Deprecated
stage 'Build'
…
```